# Writing an R function that creates columns

Tags: r, function

I want to add columns to my data frame df depending on the contents of the Column CountryID of the same dataframe. I got it to work but I have 60 of those copy-paste-lines.

```
df$Country1 <- ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 1), 1, 0)
df$Country2 <- ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 2), 1, 0)
df$Country3 <- ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 3), 1, 0)
... 60 more lines
```

To make the code a bit more organized I want to write a function createColumns that I just have to call and the entire code within the brackets will be executed. My latest attempt did not create any columns.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
createColumns <- function() {
df$Country1 <- ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 1), 1, 0)
df$Country2 <- ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 2), 1, 0)
df$Country3 <- ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 3), 1, 0)
... 60 more lines
return(invisible())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *return the new object*:

```
createColumns <- function(df) {
    df$Country1 <- ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 1), 1, 0)
    df$Country2 <- ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 2), 1, 0)
    df$Country3 <- ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 3), 1, 0)
    ... 60 more lines
    df
}
```

And use it thus:

```
df <- createColumns(df)
```

You can’t (easily) modify non-local objects in R, and this is on purpose: you *shouldn’t* do that. Instead, make assignment explicit, as done above.

---

There are some other things to note; for example, repeating what you wrote 60 times should be a huge red flag. Rethink the problem: you probably don’t want 60 columns for this in the first place (instead, research and use the concept of [tidy data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)) but if you really do, you can probably use pivot functions to replace those 60 lines of code with a single line of code.

Furthermore, R has a logical data type. This means that, in virtually all use-cases, you’d assign `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of 1 and 0. So, instead of writing

```
ifelse(as.integer(df$CountryID == 1), 1, 0)
```

You’d simplify this to

```
df$CountryID == 1
```

In addition, the `as.integer` call is *entirely redundant*: `ifelse` requires a *logical argument*, so your current code takes a logical vector, explicitly converts it to integer, and the result is converted *back* to a logical vector by `ifelse`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. 
Just one question: Why is it necessary to write df again at the end of the function? It does not work without it. Just curious

Comment: @BlackPearl A function returns the value of its last expression — since you want to return the data frame itself, that’s what needs to be last. Otherwise the function would return the value of the last assignment, which corresponds to the value of the last column only.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the desired output in a simpler manner, you can try `table` + `cbind` like below

```
newCols <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(cbind(q = 1:nrow(df),df)))
dfout <- cbind(df,`colnames<-`(newCols,paste0("Country",colnames(newCols))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  countryID Country1 Country2 Country3
1         1        1        0        0
2         3        0        0        1
3         1        1        0        0
4         2        0        1        0
5         1        1        0        0
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(countryID = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```